# How to display other user's profile

Tags: django

Please, I am creating a web app, when a user log in, he/she can see other users, and can click on the user's username to view that user's profile. But I am finding it difficult to display other users profile except the currently logged in user. Kindly help me on how to go about this. I would prefer a function based view.
**views**

```
def profile(request, username):
context = {
           'userprofile': User.objects.get(username=username),
           }
return render_to_response('profile.html',context)
```

**profile.html**

```
Name: {{ userprofile.get_full_name }}
Username: {{ userprofile.username }}
```

**urls**

```
url(r'^/profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', auth(profile), {}, name='chat_history')
```

what I don't know is how apply this url on a username. As in this:

**home.html**

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message.sender == user %}
            <p><a href="/profile/{{ xxxxx }}"> {{ message.sender }}</a> >
            <a href="/profile/{{ xxxxx }}/">{{ message.receiver }}</a> : <br/>
            {{ message.message }}
            <sub>{{ message.creation_date }}</sub>
                </p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% trans 'No chat history of you and this user' %}
{% endif %}
```

Have got no idea what 'xxxxx' should be

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How can you possibly expect us to answer this question? You've given no detail of your views, your models, your URLs, what you've tried, where you are having trouble, anything.

Comment: I find it difficult to answer your question, espcially ASAP... Have a good read here http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Yes, I tried this in my view
##def profile(request, username):
#return render_to_response('profile.html',{'userprofile': User.objects.get(username=username)})
###in my template. 'Profile.html'###
#Name: {{ userprofile.get_full_name}}
#Username: {{ userprofile.username }}
###in my urls###
#url(r'^/profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$)', profile, {},  name='profile')
########
But I find it difficult to attach a link to user's username. As in below

###home.html###
<a href='xxxxx'> username</a>

I don't know what xxxxx should be

Answer (score 0):

Probably importing `User` model from `django.contrib.auth` and passing it to your views could help.